# Pig - JsonMetadata - Could not find schema file

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

There has been a major lag time when Pig evaluates LOAD statements on certain versions of pig.

Upon switching versions of Pig (during a cluster upgrade), Pig's Grunt (and via file script as well) took 30+ seconds on each LOAD statement. This was in stark contrast to the usual <1 second needed to process each LOAD statement. Pig's debug showed the LOAD statement was evaluated in about the same manner between different versions, but what differed was especially interesting.

In Version 0.9.2 (w/ Java 8), the LOAD statement was processed in <1 second. However in Version 0.11.1 and 0.12.0, the load statement was processed in 30+ seconds with the main line differing being this one:

```
[main] DEBUG org.apache.pig.builtin.JsonMetadata - Could not find schema file for /logs/visits/*/*visits_v15*.lzo
```

That debug message was not displayed until the command finished being processed which leads me to suspect the loading of the schema data is what's hanging up the entire process. The LOAD statement completes in <1 second on 0.11.1 and 0.12.0 when I specify an exact file, but still shows the warning:

```
[main] DEBUG org.apache.pig.builtin.JsonMetadata - Could not find schema file for /logs/visits/2014-08-01/2014-08-01-23-45-07.PDT.visits_v15.server.log.lzo
```

Example Pig Script:

```
SET debug 'on';
REGISTER s3://path/to/elephant-bird.jar;
v15_data = LOAD '/logs/visits/2014-08-01/2014-08-01-23-45-07.PDT.visits_v15.server.log.lzo';
```

It doesn't matter if I use Elephant Bird or not as the same debug message comes up and the performance characteristics are the same.

There are ~60 columns in each file and there are thousands of files written per day. Oddly, running the same style script above with just a "DUMP v15_data;" often gives a failed job with this style of error:

```
java.io.IOException: Deserialization error: invalid stream header:
```

Pig Versions tested: 
0.11.1
0.12.0
0.13.0 - I believe I tested this one previously, but not as thoroughly as 0.11.1 or 0.12.0

Answer (score 1):

After struggling with this issue for a while, I found a solution was to use the "-noschema" flag. So `USING PigStorage('-noschema')`